# how can i add multiple path rout to the same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make this as multiple path, but when I do that I get a blank page. When I go back to the "/home" path, everything works fine.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: ["/", "/home"],
    element: <GeneralLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: "profile",
        element: <Profile />,
        auth: "user",
      },
    ],
  },
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `path` as `array`. Its type is `String`

```js
interface RouteObject {
  path?: string;
  index?: boolean;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  caseSensitive?: boolean;
  id?: string;
  loader?: LoaderFunction;
  action?: ActionFunction;
  element?: React.ReactNode | null;
  errorElement?: React.ReactNode | null;
  handle?: RouteObject["handle"];
  shouldRevalidate?: ShouldRevalidateFunction;
}
```

This is the official documentation from [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main):

[Route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route)

[Type Declaration](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#type-declaration)

So you should use two routes object in your routes array.